# Use Facebook api to create tabs in users facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-2.0, facebook-php-sdk

I know this is possible using the API. But my requirement is that each user has his own url and I need to get content from that particular users url for his facebok page.

Example:

User1 page: https://mysite.com/user1
User2 page: https://mysite.com/user2

I need to show  https://mysite.com/user1 in user1's facebook page and https://mysite.com/user2 on user2's facebook page

So my question is:

Is it possible to use a single app for this? or should I use seperate app for each user?

if I need to create seperate app for each user then can I create it using the api?(So that the user can use my site to create the app and use it in his facebook page)

Comment: Can anyone please answer? I am really stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didnt get your requirement clearly but still you can create separate app URLs for every user by passing a GET parameter(app_data).
For Eg. www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/app_APP_ID is your app URL

for user 1: www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/app_APP_ID?app_data=some_data1
for user 2: www.facebook.com/PAGE_NAME/app_APP_ID?app_data=some_data2

Note: GET parameter name has to be "app_data"

Comment: Hi,I have updated the question description. Hope its clear for you now.